# Simplest ATmega328P / Arduino PCB schematic for PC serial communication

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

I'm a little bit new to electronics. For a project, I needed the simplest possible form of Arduino board. The board will recieve data from the PC via serial connection, run some basic computations (using an Arduino library) on this data, and return the output to PC with serial connection. There are two basic things that I need from this board.

1. Should be Arduino bootloader burnable (If yes, how will I do it?)
2. Should be able to do serial communication via USB.

I have used ATmega 328P-MU (the SMD version) as the microcontroller and FT232RL for USB to UART conversion.

And this is my design (I'm using easyeda.com):

[image: This is my design :]

Since I'm new to electronics, I wanted to check if the design is correct and the board will run as I want, before I send the design to online PCB assembly.

Should I change anything in my design, or will it work as I wanted?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should be Arduino bootloader burnable (If yes, how will I do it?)

You need a SPI connection (pins 15, 16, 17 and reset) to your mictrocontroller in order to burn the bootloader, which is still missing from your schematic.

> Should be able to do serial communication via USB.

It should be possible, after you have burnt your microcontroller.

However, if you don't really have a very good reason for replicating an arduino board, you should just buy one arduino platform.

Comment: So, 4 male headers to pins 15,16,17 and reset on ATmega328P, and I will be able to burn the bootloader using another arduino as ISP, as usual. Is that correct?

Comment: I'd say so. Just be careful that you don't have any current limiting device in your power supply. Meaning that if something goes bad (short circuit e.g.) you might blow the usb port of your computer.